# Redirect IE 6, 7 and 8 users with htaccess

Tags: internet-explorer, .htaccess, redirect

How can I redirect users for IE versions 6-8 with htaccess to a certain directory (mysite.com/ie)?

Note: I am using Wordpress.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE [6-8]" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/ie [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hmm. It is still redirecting with IE9

Comment: Nevermind. I cleared my cache and it works. Thank you, I appreciate it.

Comment: I copy/pasted this code but it won’t do a thing. What could I be doing wrong? I already have a .htaccess file and other code in it works. It's not the first time I am working with it, so I am a bit baffled that these simple lines of yours (which I found also in other places on the web) won’t work. Any idea?

Comment: Okay, I figured it out meanwhile. I had something else wrong in the server setting that prevented this from working

Answer (score -5):

It is much more simple to handle this with a simple javascript function. You can also use HTML. 
Here's a sample of javascript that detects the browser version. You should be able to tailor this to suit your needs:

[Detecting Windows Internet Explorer More Effectively](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Just curious to know why you would say this is more efficient than using htaccess?

Comment: My mistake, let me clarify. It is much more simple.

Comment: How and why is it more simple?  What could possibly be easier than editing one little htaccess file?  More robust too.

Comment: It is MUCH easier to understand javascript than the htaccess script written above.

Comment: Regardless of the level understanding required for either, using JS on the client side is not nearly as performant as using HTACCESS or, even better, setting this directly up in the vHost. 

Just because something is easier and doesn't require as much effort to execute doesn't mean it's correct. 

PLUS you are assuming the use case of Chris Burton. What if he NEEDS this to be a server-level directive? 

Terrible answer.